# How to pass custom array of dictionaries to request body in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to pass an array of dictionaries to request body, here is sample array to pass in request.

Body :

```
[

{
    "security_question_id": 1,
    "answer": "abc",
    "user_security_question_id": 40
},

{
    "security_question_id": 3,
    "answer": "abc",
    "user_security_question_id": 41
},

{
    "security_question_id": 2,
    "answer": "abc",
    "user_security_question_id": 42
}

]
```

How can I pass above array of dictionary as an body request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data isn't in a type-safe Swift dictionary format as the values are a mix of types (Strings and Ints).  You be better holding the data in a struct and then passing an array of the structs into whatever function you need.

```
struct SecurityInfo {
   questionID: Int
   answer: String
   questionID: Int
}

func someFunction (securityInfo: [SecurityInfo]) {
  //do something with the data
}
```

However looking at the data it looks more like json than swift.  Is the question really how to import the data into a swift app?
(BTW I'm intentionally ignoring all the security issues with storing passwords as plain text :-)

Comment: Can I pass now array of struct to request body, Please provide me a sample request of body only?

Comment: @Vaibh I'm not sure what you are asking, or even what you mean by request body.  The example above shows how to pass the array of struct into a function.  I suggest you try and code it yourself and come back with more specific questions if you hit problems, and then we'll be able to give more focussed advice.